# One server and one client side form on the same page

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have two forms on an asp.net page. One is the overall form tag, with `runat="server"` and the other is a simple form with one input for search.
The form itself:

```
<form method="post" id="searchForm">
  <input type="text" id="searchstring" class="search-box" name="searchstring"
    value="Search..." />
</form>
```

the Razor script to check for postback:

```
@{
  bool isPostBack = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["searchstring"]);
  var original_value = "Search...";
  if(isPostBack)
  {
   Response.Redirect("/SearchResults/?q=" + Request["searchstring"]);
   }
  }
```

This is submitted via jQuery on enter like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $search = $('#searchstring');
original_val = "@original_value";
$search.focus(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === original_val) {
        $(this).val('');
    }
}).blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === '') {
        $(this).val(original_val);
    }
}).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $('form#searchForm').submit();
    }
}); });​
```

My problem is that once I put the search form on the page, server-side forms get disabled.
For example: I have a regular asp.net membership login control, which stops posting back once the search form is on the page.

I looked around on google for a bit, but all I could find are people talking about two SERVER side forms on one page. Maybe this is trivial, but I can't get it working.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably nesting the two forms. In this case, the outer one (or the inner one, depending on the browser) won't work.

Fixing this is quite easy: just move the contained form outside of its containing form.

Comment: That was quite easy :) Thank you!